# How to pass the date selected from datepicker to sql query using post?

Tags: php, jquery, select, datepicker

This is my VIEW(roster.php)

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1024/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1024/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1024/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1024/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1024/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<form action="time_model.php" method="post">
        From: <input type="text" id="datepicker"  name="date_from"/> <br/><br/>
        To: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="date_to" />
        </form>
<input type="submit">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get('<?=base_url()?>index.php/roster/get_emprecord', function(data) {
            if ( data.substring(0,1) == '0' ) return true;
            var emp_roster = JSON.parse(data);

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: team_dtr,
                    pageSize: 20
                },
                groupable: true,
                sortable: {
                    mode: "multiple",
                    allowUnsort: true
                },
                pageable: {
                    buttonCount: 6
                },
                scrollable: false,
                columns: [

                    {
                        field: "user_name",
                        title: "Name",
                    },

                    {
                        field: "entry_type",
                        title: "Entry Type",
                    },

                    {
                        field: "entry_datetime",
                        title: "Date",
                    }
            ]
            });
        });
    }); 
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker();
$("#datepicker2").kendoDatePicker();
</script>
```

In my view I'm selecting 2 dates(date_from, date_to) using a datepicker. Now I'm trying to send in my query(model) the dates that were selected in my view. But it seems not catching it.

This is my MODEL(time_model.php)

```
public function get_roster($end= '($_POST[date_from])', $start= '$POST[date_to]' )
{
$sql="SELECT user_name, entry_type, entry_datetime
FROM time_entries
WHERE entry_datetime 
BETWEEN' ".$start." ' AND ' ".$end." '
ORDER BY entry_datetime";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if ($result) return $result;
    return false;
}
```

This is my CONTROLLER(roster.php)

```
public function get_emprecord()
 {
  $data['title'] = "Roster";
  $result = $this->time_model->get_employee_record($data)
if ( $result ) $data['dump'] = json_encode($result);
else $data['dump'] = "0 Request can not be completed right now.";

$this->load->view(roster'', $data);
  }
```

When I try it in my controller alone it says **'0 Request can not be completed right now'**. I think the post that I'm throwing in my query is not catched because its giving 0 results. Definitely I'm doing something not right here :(.

All I just want is to get the record from my database ranging from the selected datepicker(date_from, date_to)taken in my view. Then return the result from similar view. I saw a lot of question seems like this but I don't understand the procedure how it was done. T_T. Thanks in advance for those who could help and enlighten me of my mistake.

Comment: tried dumping the values of $end and $start? I would suggest, if you continue using this way, to make smth like `function get_roster($end = NULL, $start = NULL) { if (is_null($end) && is_null($start) { $end = $_POST['date_from']; $start = $_POST['date_to']; } ...`

Comment: Putting a string in single quotes prevents variable interpolation. Why are you quoting the `$_POST` variables at all? If you want to use a variable, just write it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function get_roster()
{
    $sql="SELECT user_name, entry_type, entry_datetime
    FROM time_entries
    WHERE entry_datetime 
    BETWEEN' '{$_POST['date_from']}' AND '{$_POST['date_to']}'
    ORDER BY entry_datetime";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();

    if ($result) return $result;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not `public function get_roster()` ... `BETWEEN '{$_POST['date_from']}'` then, the $_POST is superglobal, don't need to pass it as param

Comment: @RoyalBg you are right man. i just have updated my answer. thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

$_POST is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method. If you want to access the variable you have access like $_POST['date_form'].

So the you can use the post directly into query.

```
$sql="SELECT user_name, entry_type, entry_datetime
FROM time_entries
WHERE entry_datetime 
BETWEEN '".$_POST['date_form']."' AND ' ".$_POST['date_to']."'
ORDER BY entry_datetime";
```

Make sure the date format should be mysql format i.e(YYY-mm-dd)

Refer :http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php